# Шифрование картинок с помощью CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, шифрование, cryptojs

Стоит задача написать программу на JS (клиент онли), которая шифрует содержимое произвольных файлов (их может быть очень много и большого размера) с помощью введенного юзером пароля по стандартному криптостойкому алгоритму. После исследования требований выбрал алгоритм RC4 и его реализацию из библиотеки CryptoJS.

Сейчас имею такой код: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_js_developer/nuevwrp0/.

Вводите пароль, хеш пароля - это ключ при шифровке и расшифровке файла.
Текстовые файлы обрабатывает отлично (`.txt`, `.js`). А вот, например, картинки ломает нещадно. Я так понимаю, мне нужно конвертировать изображения в поток битов и шифровать уже его? Или есть другое, более правильное/быстрое решение?

Спасибо!

---

**UPD**
В ходе дальнейшего исследования выяснилось, что RC4 хоть и обеспечивает какую-то криптостойкость, но есть алгоритмы получше. Например, AES. Так-же, для генерации ключа из строки-пароля лучше не использовать обычные функции хеширования, т. к. они разрабатывались **быстрыми**. Для усложнения взлома с помощью грубой силы, лучше всего использовать алгоритм pbkdf2 или bcrypt. Они значительно усложняют атаку.

Comment: Конвертировать сначала в base64, а потом шифровать не вариант?

Comment: @Neverm1ndo, помимо экономии времени и места, мне ещё нужно сохранять файлы как они есть, т.е. с метаданными. Так-же, хочется работать и с видео, с `.exe` и вообще с любым типом файлов. Если вы подскажете код для этого, то промежуточная конвертация в `base64` хоть и нежелательна, но имеет место быть, если бенчмарки будут удовлетворительными

Comment: Думается, проблема в том, что вы в файл сохраняете не бинарные данные, а конвертируете в строку. Далее, после расшифровки вы делаете `toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)`. Для строк это работает, но если у вас изначально были бинарные данные, то зачем это преобразование байтов в строку? Нужно избавиться от всех этих преобразований в строки, работайте с бинарными данными, храните зашифрованные данные в бинарном виде, и после расшифровки сохраняйте бинарные данные как есть в файл

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Можете дать примеры кода?

Comment: думаю можно переводить файл в [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272491/6750422) а при декодировании обратно [base64 в файл](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940290/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-javascript-file-object-like-as-from-file-input-f)

Comment: @DaniilLoban, подскажите пример кода?

Comment: @Alexander вы смотрели 2 ссылки которые я скинул? если нужно могу подсказать конечно

Comment: @DaniilLoban, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с base64 понадобятся 2 функции

```
const fileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
  reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});

const base64ToFile = (url, filename, mimeType) => {
  return (fetch(url)
    .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
    .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], filename,{type:mimeType});})
  );
}
```

( ссылки на исходный код [fileToBase64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272491/6750422), [base64ToFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940290/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-javascript-file-object-like-as-from-file-input-f) )

Существующие функции нужно будет подправить следующим образом, внедрив в них шаг кодирования и декодирования base64:

```
encryptNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!passNode.value) return alert('Password input is empty! Aborting.');
  const pass = CryptoJS.SHA3(passNode.value);
  pickAFile(false).then(async(file) => {
    const data = await fileToBase64(file)
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.RC4.encrypt(data, pass).toString();
    download(encrypted, `encrypted-${file.name}`, file.type);
  });
});

decryptNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!passNode.value) return alert('Password input is empty! Aborting.');
  const pass = CryptoJS.SHA3(passNode.value);
  pickAFile(false).then((file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async(e) => {
      try {
        const decrypted = CryptoJS.RC4.decrypt(e.target.result, pass);
        const typedArray = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(decrypted);
        const data = await base64ToFile(new TextDecoder().decode(typedArray),
         `decrypted-${file.name}`, file.type)
        download(data, `decrypted-${file.name}`, file.type);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('wrong password!', error);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
});
```